# Projective & injective dimensions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, homological-dimension

$A$ a Noetherian local ring, $M\neq 0$ a finite $A$-module. I'm not quite sure about the relation between finiteness of projective and injective dimensions of $M$. Does the finiteness (or infiniteness) of one necessarily imply the finiteness (or infiniteness) of another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To complement Mariano's answer: If finite projective dimension implies finite injective dimension for any module $M$, then $R$ better have finite injective dimension (the converse is also quite easy).

The local rings $R$ which have finite inj. dim. over themselves are also known as [Gorenstein rings](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209199). In fact, a theorem by Foxby says that $R$ possesses a module of both finite proj. and inj. dim. if and only if $R$ is Gorenstein.

Comment: Thanks. How do I see that if $R$ has a finite injective dimension then finite projective dimension of $M$ implies finite injective dimension of $M$?

Comment: You can use induction on the length of the min. free res. of $M$, for instance. 

Comment: I'm sorry, I still have no idea how to proceed. To begin with, if $A$ has a finite injective dimension and $M$ is projective over $A$, why does $M$ have a finite injective dimension? If you could point to any reference that would be great, too.

Comment: @kwan: break the res. into short exact sequences and use the fact that if 2 modules have fi. inj. dim., so is the third one. For ref (without proof), look at "Cohen-Macaulay rings" 1st ed by Bruns-Herzog, Section 3.1, esp. exer. 3.1.25. 

Comment: Thanks. The same method (of using minimal free resolution) doesn't seem to work to show the converse, if $A$ is Gorenstein and $M$ has a finite injective dimension then $M$ has a finite projective dimension. I tried to use finite injective resolution instead but it doesn't seem to work either. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @kwan: here is a proof from top of my head, but there might be easier ones: replacing $M$ by high syzygy, can assume $M$ is max. Cohen-Macaulay. Then kill a full reg. seq., -> assume $R$ is Artinian. But then $M$ is injective, so projective.  

Comment: Thanks. In the last step, what was the condition exactly that allowed you to conclude that $M$ is projective from $M$ being injective? 

Answer (score 13):

No. For example, there are rings $A$ for which the residue field $k$ is of infinite projective dimension but of finite injective dimension. On the other hand, if $k$ is of finite projective dimension, then $A$ is of finite global dimension, so $k$ (and everything else) has finite injective dimension.

For a small non-commutative example, consider the algebra $A$ which is the quotient of the path algebra of the quiver

[image: diagram]

modulo the ideal generated by $\beta\alpha$ and $\beta^2$. Then the simple module supported on the vertex $1$ is an injective of infinite projective dimension. By duality, the opposite algebra has a projective module of infinite injective dimension.